# Add new row in gridview while button onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my program that page load the gridview and retrieve the database record to textbox and i put a add new button wish to add new row exactly like that row but the textbox is empty.

[image]

I wanted to create a new row in `GridView` while click add new button while my `TextBox` is retrieve data from database. I try to run the code but it is nothing happen when i click the button. Hope someone may help. Thanks.

My front end code

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="display_none">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium">Name</asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="display_none">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="NormalInputTextField" Text='<%#Eval("SLMN") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="display_none">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CommandName="remove" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField FooterStyle-BorderStyle="None" HeaderStyle-CssClass="display_none">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="BtnSearch2" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="btn btn-primary"  CommandName="ViewComments" OnClientClick="javascript:saveData(this,'grid')"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" BorderStyle="None"/>
    <FooterTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="BtnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click"/>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

My back end code

```
private void AddNewRowToGrid()
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     DataRow dr = null;
     dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
     dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
     dr = dt.NewRow();
     dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
     dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

My onclick event to call add new function

```
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddNewRowToGrid();
}
```

**My gridview tag**

```
<grd:MultiSelectGridView ID="grid2" runat="server" Width="500px" 
                        CssClass="paging_gridview" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns ="false" PageSize="10" PagerType="Custom"  
                        ShowFooter="true" OnRowDeleting="grid2_RowDeleting" 
                        MultiSelectDataKeyName="Urid,Name" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                        MultiSelectColumnIndex="0" EnableMultiSelect="false" GridLines="None" BorderStyle="None" OnRowCommand="grid2_RowCommand"
                        >
```

i bind my record to gridview by page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Loadgrid();
    }
}

private void Loadgrid()
{
    string branch = txtBranch.Text.Trim();
    string name = txtName.Text.Trim();

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM fcs_cotmdl WHERE TMDL= '" + name + "'AND CONO='" + branch + "' ";

    SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr_epsi"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString.Replace("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;", "");
    SqlDataSource con = new SqlDataSource();

    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = sql;
    grid2.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource2";
    grid2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You create a new DataTable, add a single empty `DataRow` and then you're doing nothing with that table. Do you really expect that this code adds a new row to an existing DataSource? The right way is to load the `DataSource` from database since it could have been changed meanwhile. Then you can add another row easily. Afterwards you assign it as DataSource to your GridView and call `DataBind`.

Comment: I haven't looked at your wall of code yet, but the fact that you're instantiating a new `DataTable` instance instead of fetching an existing one looks rather fishy.

Comment: I dont see connection/binding between your datatable and gridview.

Comment: get your dataTable, through which you have bind your gridview, then add your newly created row to old datatable, Then rebind your gridview.

Comment: @TimSchmelter hi, im no idea on how to do it... i wanted the new row as same as the existing row that with database record in textbox but only if the new row textbox is empty..

Comment: Please, post your `asp:GridView` tag

Comment: @RubensFarias updated.

Comment: @TimSchmelter hi i've updated my question...

Comment: @DarkKnight hi,i've updated my question

Comment: @lc. hi,updated my question..

Comment: And how you bind your current DataSource to your GridView?

Comment: @RubensFarias hi,thanks for reply.. i've updated...

Comment: I think you need to dynamically create all the rows instead of using the Templates. Use the GetNewDataFromDB() function and get new rows from the database or just GetAllDataFromDB() and use the ForEach Loop to create rows inside the Gridview.

Comment: Check this tutorial out. It deals with the exact same issue that you have. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Adding-Dynamic-Rows-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control-with-TextBoxes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Following tutorial details the exact same scenario. Please refer to it.
[Adding Dynamic Rows to Gridview on Button Click](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Adding-Dynamic-Rows-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control-with-TextBoxes.aspx)

```
private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");
 //Instead of all the textboxes, use the button as you require.
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }
```

And then the SetPreviousData() Function:

```
private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then inside your Click Event:

```
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From your Load grid method you should retrieve the data as a data table and bind to grid. And save in in session. Like this:

```
private void Loadgrid()
        {

            var dt = new DataTable();

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ToString()))
            {

                var command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[T1]";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (var adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
                    adaptor.Fill(dt);
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
                }

            }

                Session["ss"] = dt;
                grid2.DataSource = dt;
                grid2.DataBind();

            }


private void AddNewRowToGrid()
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable) Session["ss"];
            DataRow dr = null;
            DataRow newBlankRow1 = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.Add(newBlankRow1);
            grid2.DataSource = dt;
            grid2.DataBind();

            Session["ss"] = dt;
        }
```

After add an empty row also you need to bind data to grid again.

Comment: DataTable dt = ToDataTable(res);-->> the res is not content in current context...